# Postgres -h connection works but without -h option gets Peer authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, psql

the below commands works

```
psql -h localhost -U <username> <dbname>
```

but

```
psql localhost -U <username> <dbname>
```

the above get psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user

Answer (score 0):

`-h` option lets you provide the `hostname` for your psql connection. If you remove `-h` option, then also remove `localhost` from your statement.

You can also check `pg_hba.conf` file for more debugging.

Comment: Y is it like if connects via -h it connect and without it, it shows error ?

Comment: Try `psql -U <username> <dbname> ` (If you remove `-h`, then remove its value too)

Answer (score 0):

Because as @Lohit Gupta stated without `-h` psql ignores the hostname(localhost) and uses the default connection type. From docs:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS

"
host

Name of host to connect to. If a host name begins with a slash, it specifies Unix-domain communication rather than TCP/IP communication; the value is the name of the directory in which the socket file is stored. The default behavior when host is not specified, or is empty, is to connect to a Unix-domain socket in /tmp (or whatever socket directory was specified when PostgreSQL was built). On machines without Unix-domain sockets, the default is to connect to localhost.
"

So in your case you have switched from connection type host to type local and a different set of connection rules will take over. As mentioned look in your pg_hba.conf file to see what those are. You should have also received the following error:

`psql: warning: extra command-line argument "localhost" ignored`